# How to Source YADCF Select Filter Options with Response Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, django-rest-framework, yadcf

Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5sgc03my/. I have a DataTable with a couple YADCF filters:

```
var oTable = $('#example').DataTable({
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {"url": "/platform/activities/?format=datatables",
         "dataSrc": function(json){
           yadcf_data_1 = json.options.activity_type
           console.log(yadcf_data_1)
           return json.data;
          }
        },
});
console.log(yadcf_data_1)

yadcf.init(oTable,
      [
        {
          column_number : 0,
          filter_type: "range_date",
        },
        {
          column_number : 1,
          filter_type: "select",
          select_type: "select2",
        },
```

`/platform/activities/?format=datatables` returns this response:

```
{"recordsTotal":23286,"recordsFiltered":23286,
"data":[{"id":104,"activity_type":"Option 1",}],
"draw":1,
"options":{"activity_type":[{"label":"Option 1","value":1},
                            {"label":"Option 2","value":2},]}}
```

Currently, the filter for `activity_type` column (column 1) returns only `Option 1`, because that's all that's available in the table. Therefore, I want to point the filter to the `activity_type` array in the `options` portion of the Ajax response. I know there is the `data` option that can be set for each filter, but I'm unsure how to point it to the key:value array. When I put `console.log(yadcf_data_2);` outside of the DataTable construction, it just prints `undefined`. This is being printed prior to the console call in the ajax function.

How would I tie YADCF to the `activity_type` array?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [yadcf showcase server page](http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/server_side_source.html) , you should send the `yadcf_data_0 / yadcf_data_1` along with the `recordsTotal` / `data`

You also can debug the [xhr event](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/536664081f781949b074f93144f31aaa79ce7a34/src/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L4019) inside the yadcf code to see whats going on

> //In case that you want to populate your select / auto_complete filters with values
>
> //you have to add to your current JSON the following attributes yadcf_data_0 / yadcf_data_1 / etc'
>
> //where each attribute contains a list of strings
>
> //For example:
>
> //"yadcf_data_0":["KHTML","Webkit","Trident","Misc","Other browsers","Tasman","Presto","Gecko"],
>
> //"yadcf_data_1":["Nintendo DS browser",

Comment: first, thank you for making an excellent product. so with Django, I am using a helper library that converts an API (DRF) into the format needed for DataTables. That library provides the `options` attribute to pass extra data to the server. In other words, is there a way to convert the `options` portion of my response into something that would feed into yadcf_data_0, etc.?

Comment: can't tell without a link to a test page for debugging , I suggest you to put a break point in that xhr code I told you and see what can be done there

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1xsfqgpu/10/ - this isn't working fully, I can't figure out why the data is not flowing into the table, but it is a start.

Comment: ok, let me know when you'll have a working example and I will take a look

Comment: alright - here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/5sgc03my/. The filter is currently pulling from the table itself, I am wondering how to pull from the `activity_type` list of dictionaries. My thought is to include a list of dictionaries for each field I want to filter on.

Comment: when working with serverSide true your server is the one that should do the filtering logic and return only the relevant row, I don't quite understand what are you trying to achieve here / whats wrong in your opinion

Comment: The server will do the filtering, I just need all the available options to be populated in the yadcf select2 box. Right now, only options that are in the current page are included in the dropdown, and this makes sense. To combat this, I am passing in a list of options with the JSON response from the AJAX call. That list of options makes it to the browser. How do I feed that list of options into the dropdown? In the JSFiddle, `Option 1`, `Option 2`, and `Option 3` should be shown in the dropdown.

Comment: Then your server should return yadcf_data_0 / yadcf_data_1 / yadcf_data_2 / etc populated with list of string for the relevant filters and yadcf will make use of that data to populate the filters

Comment: so there is no way to populate yadcf with the JSON response in the way it is now?

Comment: @OverflowingTheGlass, sorry for late response, not that Im aware of, but will try to look into it

Comment: @OverflowingTheGlass , recently a new feature was added to yadcf `exRefreshColumnFilterWithDataProp` that might help you, look at the docs in js file and read the PR description https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/pull/573 , you might need to ask on datatables forum on where to place the `exRefreshColumnFilterWithDataProp` function, because I noticed that when I'm using ajax -> success it prevents from dt.xhr event (inside yadcf code) to be executed

Comment: any thoughts on this now? I haven't had much luck getting anything working, and I can't find many/any examples/docs of exRefreshColumnFilterWithDataProp currently.

Comment: I'm getting a `TypeError: yadcf.exRefreshColumnFilterWithDataProp is not a function` when placing it after `yadcf.init(oTable)...`

Comment: @OverflowingTheGlass use latest beta, read here https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/pull/573 and check this http://jsfiddle.net/rmahnwce/

Comment: so is this only useful when adding new records? I'm looking for the initial population to be done through an element in the JSON response.

Comment: @OverflowingTheGlass if you are using "serverSide": true then it should work, look at the sample http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/server_side_source.html in case of additional question ask a new question with all the details